# Print a diagonal triangle in java

Tags: java

I need to print out a triangle that looks like this:

```
*
 **
  ***
   ****
```

The code I have right now

```
    for(line = 0; line < size; line++){
        for(count = 0; count < line; count++){
            System.out.print("*");
            for(space = 0; space < line; space++)
                System.out.print(" ");
        }
            System.out.println();
    }
```

I get this

```
* 
**  
***   
****    
*****     
******
```

Comment: temporarily replace the spaces with + or some other character and it will be a bit more evident what is happening

Comment: What exactly is that pattern you're trying to achieve? I mean you shown it but I don't see a fixed pattern there. Can you describe that in words?

Comment: The code you give us does not produce the second pattern

Comment: It is more related to algorithms not just java

Answer (score 2):

```
for(line = 0; line < size; line++){
    for(space = 0; space < line; ++space)
        System.out.print(" ");
    for(count = 0; count < line; count++)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the spaces on the same line. Call `System.out.println();` before printing the spaces.

Edit - Example:

```
for (line = 0; line < size; line++){
    for(space = 0; space < line - 1; space++)
        System.out.print(" ");
    for (count = 0; count < line; count++)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first print the prefix spaces. and then print the stars.

Have a try with this:

```
    int line = 0;
    int size = 6;
    int count = 0;
    int space = 0;
    for (line = 0; line < size; line++) {
        //print spaces
        for (space = 0; space < line; space++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        //Print stars
        //Note: here count condition should be count < line+1, rather than count < line
        //If you do not do so, the first star with print as space only.
        for (count = 0; count < line+1; count++) {
            System.out.print("*");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Output in console:

```
*
 **
  ***
   ****
    *****
     ******
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Pyramid 
   {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       java.util.Scanner pyr=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("type a no. to make Pyramid");
       int n= pyr.nextInt();
       for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
       {
           for(int j=n; j>i; j--)
           {
               System.out.print(" ");
           } 
           for(int k=1; k<=i; k++)
           {
              System.out.print("* ");
           }
            System.out.println(); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just printing the spaces before the asterisks would be fine.